# Carousel with left en right button. Check on left and right button

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

I have a problem with my carousel. I've searched for similar questions. But found nothing.

I have make a carousel with three sections and a big image. And the carousel have a right and left navigate button. In the beginning, the first section is show. With a right carousel button. The left button is hidden. Because you can not click on the left. When you click to the other slide. The next section is show and the background image is animate 1000 pixels to the right.

You can see here the example: [Example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/upyZH/)

But now the problem. When i am on the first section. I have a right navigate button. The left button is hidden, because you can not click on it. When you are on the last section. The left button is show and the right button is hide.

But the problem is the middle section. When you are on the middle section. You have a navigatie button to the right. But not a navigate button to the left. And when I'm in the middle. I also left. And not just to the right.

How can i fix this in my script. Thanks for help.

You can change the code and see the code on jsfiddle.

***[Here you can see the code and example](http://jsfiddle.net/upyZH/)***

Comment: What I've usually have done is to have a variabel called state. The state is 0 at load. When you browse (in your case) to the right, the state is set to 1. Then you simply have a function that checks the state, if it's 0, hide the left arrow, if it's 1, show all arrows, if it's 2, hide right arrow. Should not be that hard

Comment: Can you give me a example on jsfiddle. I am beginning javascripter. Hope that you can help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made an example of my idea here: http://jsfiddle.net/upyZH/5/ , but the problem is still there. Firebug keeps telling me that the image sprite.png was not found. Perhaps that is your problem? And what are all those random charcaters in the css?

EDIT: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/upyZH/8/ , works like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at my fiddle here: http://jsbin.com/abape3/14 It has the left and right buttons and works like what you've described.